# solve $\int x^{-c} \left( 1 + y(x)^2 \right)^{-\frac{a+1}{2}} dy$ where $e^y = x^c + bx$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I am trying to make some progress on solving the following integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{-c} \left( 1 + y(x)^2 \right)^{-\frac{a+1}{2}} dy$$
with $y(x)$ defined as
$$e^y = x^c + bx$$
for $a \in \mathbb{N}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}_+$, $c \in \mathbb{R}_+$.

In the interesting parameter values (low $a$ and $c$), the integral seems to diverge to $+\infty$ at the left and sometimes also at the right tail. If the standard Riemann integral can not be taken, I wonder if there is other way of assigning some reasonable value to it.

My attempts so far:

1. I considered taking Cauchy Principal Value (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), but as far as I understand it's not applicable to tail infinities of the same sign.
2. I considered methods of contour integration (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration), but am not really familiar with them and not sure if they can help here.
3. I was also thinking about multiplying the function by some special integrator $\psi_\lambda(x)$ where $\lambda$ is some parameter, which would allow taking the integral analytically, and then $\lambda$ could be sent to some limiting value forcing it to vanish from the integral's computed value. But so far I could not come up with the multiplier that works.
4. Taking CPV or integrating numerically in Mathematica did not really help (CPV returns nothing, and numeric response does not seem wrong, just says the answer is infinity):

```
In[5]:= f1[x_] := (x^(-c))*(c*x^(c - 1) + b)/(x^c + b*x);
f2[x_] := (1 + (Log[x^c + b*x])^2)^(-(a + 1)/2);
FullSimplify[f1[x]*f2[x]]
Integrate[f1[x]*f2[x], {x, 0, Infinity}, PrincipalValue -> True, 
 Assumptions -> c > 1 && b > 0 && a >= 1]


Out[7]= (x^-c (b + c x^(-1 + c)) (1 + Log[b x + x^c]^2)^(
 1/2 (-1 - a)))/(b x + x^c)

Out[8]= Integrate[(
 x^-c (b + c x^(-1 + c)) (1 + Log[b x + x^c]^2)^(1/2 (-1 - a)))/(
 b x + x^c), {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, PrincipalValue -> True, 
 Assumptions -> c > 1 && b > 0 && a >= 1]

In[9]:= f1[x_] := (x^(-c))*(c*x^(c - 1) + b)/(x^c + b*x);
f2[x_] := (1 + (Log[x^c + b*x])^2)^(-(a + 1)/2);
a = 1
b = 0.01
c = 2
NIntegrate[f1[x]*f2[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]


Out[11]= 1

Out[12]= 0.01

Out[13]= 2

During evaluation of In[9]:= NIntegrate::zeroregion: Integration region {{0.,0}} cannot be further subdivided at the specified working precision. NIntegrate assumes zero integral there and on any further indivisible regions.

During evaluation of In[9]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {8.20436012733972239411703426966037959256020034621446731577251829666*10^-76}. NIntegrate obtained 1.4003271797860882`*^148 and 1.466921574402827`*^148 for the integral and error estimates.

Out[14]= 1.40033*10^148
```

I would appreciate all the suggestions, negative results with explanations would also help.

**Extra**:
An alternative way to write down this integral is substituting out $y$ (with the corresponding correction term):
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{-c} \frac{cx^{c-1}+b}{x^c+bx} \left( 1 + (\ln(x^c+bx))^2 \right)^{-\frac{a+1}{2}} dx$$

**P.S.** I have posted earlier a formulation of this question without Mathematica implementation details at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3732709/solve-int-x-c-left-1-yx2-right-fraca12-dy-where-ey-x

Comment: When defining functions use pattern objects ([`_`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html)) on the LHS of the definitions, e.g., `f1[x_] := ...` and `f2[x_] := ...` and when defining constants use `Set` rather than `SetDelayed`, e.g., `a = 1; b = 0.01; c = 2;`

Comment: NIntegrate is given c for the integration variable after c is set equal 2, made a constant. The use as input into one input cell results into the use of a,b and c as constants in all evalualtion. At least the first four inputs are intended that way?

Comment: `Reduce[Exp[y] == x^c + b x, y]` gives `C[1] \[Element] Integers && x (1. + 100. x) != 0 && 
 y == (0. + 6.28319 I) C[1] + Log[0.01 x (1. + 100. x)]` and `Solve[Exp[y] == x^c + b x, y]` gives `{{y -> 1. Log[0.01000000000000000 x + x^2]}}`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the syntax and typo corrections, I amended the posting. @SteffenJaeschke: I'm not sure how to interpret your second comment, could you please expand?